# Are regression problems more likely to overfit than classification problems?

Tags: regression, classification, overfitting

I will illustrate my question on an example:
Let's say we have a dataset that we want to split into two disjoint sets of similar size.
The dataset has a high dimensional feature (several hundred variables) and a float label for each sample.

We could try performing linear regression on our set and then find a threshold that splits our dataset in an optimal way.
Alternatievely we could first split the training data (based on a clustering method for example) and then use classification to divide the dataset.

Intuition would suggest that the first way is better, because it would take into acount the distance between a given sample and the threshold. This should reduce the number of misclassified samples that are far from the border between the two sets.

My tests on the other hand suggest that for small datasets the second method generalizes better than the first method. For larger datasets the regression is better.

This leads me to believe that classification problems are less prone to overfitting.

Comment: 1) Can you explain your alternative method better?                      2) How did you get the float label for your training samples?  Are they somehow related to the class?  In a classification algorithm we usually have labels which are categorical rather than ordinal.  Unless somehow you came up with your own measure ...

Comment: Ok, so the data has no classes, each label is a real number, they are measurements of a process. Division into two classes is what I would like to obtain, that division has to generalize well to new data. Does that also take care of answering question 1)?